# Adding a FULLTEXT index on existing db

Tags: mysql, fulltext-index

I have a MySQL table that has 165,716 records (and counting). The table is 233,3 MB large. Now I want to add a FULLTEXT index to a column in that table. Is that possible, or is it going to be a problem?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if the table is running the MyISAM engine, but it's likely to take a long time to complete the initial indexing.

[edit]I misread the size - I thought it was 2.3GB, not 233MB! If that's the case, the indexing shouldn't take that long.

Comment: Tnx, I am running the MyISAM engine, so that's not a problem :). I was wondering about the 160k+ records, if that would be any problem!

Comment: It would only be a problem if the table is under regular use and the downtime due to the table locking (which is hard to predict) would cause problems. If you can, duplicate the table and time how long it takes to index the duplicate.